# Remove lines from a file based on patterns in another file which may partially match a particular column in first file

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have searched for similar answers but none solve the partial match problem. 
Patterns file is file2 and lines to be removed are in file1.csv which is a pretty big file with far more columns than those represented here.

I have the following fields in file1.csv:

**UPDATE:**

```
Linking page,Last crawled
https://start.me/discover/be/entertainment/betting?locale=ro,"Nov 17, 2018"
https://imgcop.com/img/Bwin-Mobile-App-77898390/,"Nov 17, 2018"
https://start.me/site/unibet.be?locale=fr,"Nov 17, 2018"
https://poker.partypoker402.com/en/blog/matt-savage-talks-wpt500.html,"Nov 17, 2018"
```

file2 contains:

```
https://roulette2.tk
paradisebingo.t
paradisebingo.tm
free-bwin.ro
sb288.co

OUTPUT
Linking page,Last crawled
Linking page,Last crawled
Linking page,Last crawled
Linking page,Last crawled
Linking page,Last crawled
https://start.me/discover/be/entertainment/betting?locale=ro,"Nov 17, 2018"
https://start.me/discover/be/entertainment/betting?locale=ro,"Nov 17, 2018"
https://start.me/discover/be/entertainment/betting?locale=ro,"Nov 17, 2018"
https://start.me/discover/be/entertainment/betting?locale=ro,"Nov 17, 2018"
https://start.me/discover/be/entertainment/betting?locale=ro,"Nov 17, 2018"
etc....
```

The output is being repeated. I am not sure what is wrong.

```
awk 'FNR == NR{ neg[$1]; next } { for ( i in neg ) if ( $1 !~ i) print }' file2.txt FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' file1.csv > out.csv
```

but can't get it to work. For some strange reason grep fails:

```
grep -vwF -f file2 file1.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: Your `grep` command works for me. I see no reason why you have to use the `-w` and `-F` parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Inian’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/497125/80216#497126) works perfectly when `file2` is only one line long,
and is a good start on a more general answer. 
But I believe that

```
awk 'FNR == NR { neg[$1]; next } { ok=1; for (i in neg) if ($2 ~ i) ok=0; if (ok) print }' file2 FS="," file1
```

will do what you want in general. 
Like your answer, it starts by reading `file2` and storing its contents
(the patterns that you want to remove from `file`) in an array. 
Like Inian’s answer, it then reads `file1`. 
For each line in `file1`, it loops through the patterns from `file2`. 
We assume that the line is OK; if it matches any pattern, then it’s not OK. 
If it is still OK after checking all the patterns, we print it.

---

But I put `FS=","` as an argument between `file2` and `file1`
just because that’s the way Inian did it. 
It doesn’t matter what **f**ield **s**eparator we use when we read `file2`,
as long as it doesn’t appear therein — and `file2` contains no commas. 
So we could simplify the above a little
by specifying the field separator the ‘normal’ way —
with a `-F` option at the beginning of the command:

```
awk -F, 'FNR == NR { neg[$1]; next } { ok=1; for (i in neg) if ($2 ~ i) ok=0; if (ok) print }' file2 file1
```

You can use `-F","` if you prefer; they’re equivalent.

---

The test `FNR == NR` is so popular and pervasive
that we use it without thinking. 
`FNR` is the line number (a.k.a. record number) *within the current file,*
and `NR` is the line number *across all input.* 
So, for example,

```
$ cat cats
Felix
Garfield
Heathcliff

$ cat dogs
Lassie
Marmaduke
Snoopy

$ awk '{ print FNR, NR, $0 }' cats dogs
1 1 Felix
2 2 Garfield
3 3 Heathcliff
1 4 Lassie
2 5 Marmaduke
3 6 Snoopy
```

… and so `FNR` and `NR` are equal
for each line of the first file to be processed,
and not in subsequent file(s). 
And so we use `FNR == NR` to test whether we are processing the first file.

But this is actually a bad practice. 
What if the first file is empty?

```
$ cat unicorns

$ wc unicorns
      0       0       0 unicorns

$ awk '{ print FNR, NR, $0 }' unicorns dogs
1 1 Lassie
2 2 Marmaduke
3 3 Snoopy
```

`FNR == NR` is true *for the first file **that actually has data**.* 
If your `file2` will never ever ever be empty,
you may be able to get away with ignoring this issue. 
But, based on the definition of your problem,
if `file2` is empty, the output should be all of `file1`,
because we aren’t removing anything. 
But, if you run the above command with an empty `file2`,
you will get *no* output,
because `awk` thinks it’s reading the first file (`file2`)
when it’s actually reading the second file (`file1`).

A safer way to do this is to put an assignment between the file arguments:

```
awk -F, 'FILE != 2 { neg[$1]; next } { ok=1; for (i in neg) if ($2 ~ i) ok=0; if (ok) print }' file2 FILE=2 file1
```

---

The question is a little ambiguous. 
What does “partial match” mean, *exactly*? 
Inian chose to interpret it in the sense that the question suggests
— like `grep`. 
If any value from `file2`
matches the value from the second column of `file1`
*as a regular expression,*
then remove that line of `file1`. 
But there are two problems with this.

1. The surprise factor. 
   I took the files in the question and added a

   ```
   154376352,"http://sb288eco.tm","example4"
   ```

   line to `file1`, and ran my first command. 
   That `"example4"` line was not output,
   because `sb288.co` (from `file2`), taken as a regular expression
   (in which **`.`** means “match any character”), matched `sb288eco`.

   If that’s what you want and expect to happen,
   you might as well stop reading this now.
2. Regular expression processing is computationally expensive. 
   Regular expressions have to be parsed and processed. 
   This will likely take more time than simple string comparison.

We can solve both of the above issues
by testing whether the *string* from `file2`
is present in the value from `file1` with awk’s `index` function:

```
awk -F, 'FILE != 2 { neg[$1]; next } { ok=1; for (i in neg) if (index($2,i) > 0) ok=0; if (ok) print }' file2 FILE=2 file1
```

With the above, a **`.`** in `file2` matches only a **`.`** in `file1`,
and not any other character. 
I invite you to test the above on your data and see whether it is any faster.

---

P.S. I just noticed that you changed the file format
since I posted my answer. 
Originally you wanted to test the values from `file2`
against values from the *second* column of `file1`. 
Now you seem to want to test
against values from the ***first*** column of `file1`. 
To accommodate this change,
you should take the part of any of the above answers
that compares `$2` to `i`, and change it to use `$1` instead. 
Or, if you really want to test the entire line from `file1`, use `$0`.

---

So, bottom line, you might want to use

```
awk -F, 'FILE != 2 { neg[$1]; next } { ok=1; for (i in neg) if (index($1,i) > 0) ok=0; if (ok) print }' file2 FILE=2 file1
```

as your command. 
With line breaks for readability, that’s

```
awk -F, 'FILE != 2 { neg[$1]; next }
                   {
                     ok=1
                     for (i in neg)
                             if (index($1,i) > 0) ok=0
                     if (ok) print
                   }' \
        file2 FILE=2 file1
```

Comment: awk liner works...is there a way of speeding up the process?

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks a decent attempt, but the clause for regex match does not work as you wanted it to do. In `$2 !~ neg[$1]` on the `file1`, you are trying to look up the value of `neg['156398439']` because the `$1` will be retrieved from the second file and *not* the first. So your condition would never match.

You can do something like below where you take the regex comparison inside the action part on `file1` by having a loop

```
awk 'FNR == NR { neg[$1]; next }{ for ( i in neg ) if ( $2 !~ i) print  }' file2 FS="," file1
```

Also I don't think `FS` can take that complex a regular expression to de-limit CSV files, remember `FS` defines what de-limiter to split on and not on how to define fields. You seem to have had an expression that explains how the field should look like. GNU `awk` allows another variable `FPAT` to define such regular expression.

You can use

```
awk 'FNR == NR { neg[$1]; next }{ for ( i in neg ) if ( $2 !~ i) print  }' file2 FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' file1
```

Comment: The 2nd awk answer takes forever and after cancelling the command, I find that each line is being printed multiple times within the output file(when redirected). I have made sure that the output file is named differently from file1.
`wc -l` shows 636316 lines whereas my input file has only 963 lines!!

Comment: @MallikKumar: I've tested the answer on your given input. It seems to work fine.

Comment: This works perfectly when `file2` is only one line long.  However, in general, it prints a line from `file1` if *any* pattern from `file2` doesn’t match it — and prints each line from `file1` *n* or *n* − 1 times. You should *remove* (i.e., suppress) a line if any pattern matches it, and print a line only if ***all*** the patterns don’t match it.

Comment: I have updated my question with real data and the results of @G-Man 's solutions also.